# jquery init function

Tags: jquery, function, user-interface, widget, init

I got a simple UI widget and i'd like it to alert() the "hello world!!!" when initialised.

```
$.widget("ui.myWidget", {
   _init: function() {
      //start
      alert('Hello World!!!');
   }
}
```

could some one explain how this init or _init function works.?
if i was to call the ui just like the dialog ui would `$('#selector').dialog()` 
in other words if a click `<div onclick="$('#id').myWidget()">Click Me</div>` then i should get the alert to pop up.

this code is short because i didnt want to put a lot of coding into it so its easy to read.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes when you call $('#id').myWidget(); it will trigger your _init function to run and fire the alert.

Here is a [short post](http://blog.petersendidit.com/post/stateful-jquery-plugins-with-jquery-uis-widget-factory/) about using the [jQuery UI widget factory](http://blog.petersendidit.com/post/stateful-jquery-plugins-with-jquery-uis-widget-factory/)